# Method with args inside an event handler with java

Tags: java, eventhandler

Okay, Hi guys. Currently I am taking an online course and for my final project i opted to do blackjack. Everything is running fine except for when a player needs to "hit" for another card. I  have the code required for a hit within a method which uses args from a different method i created

```
public void Hitcardp1(int p1total, String p1scard1, String p1scard2){
   int p1hitcard;

    p1hitcard = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
    p1total = p1total + p1hitcard;
    P1Area.setText("Card: " +p1scard1+ "\nCard: " +p1scard2+ "\nCard: +p1hitcard);
}
```

I need to put this in an event handler for when the hit button is clicked or interacted with. However it comes up with an error saying:

"*Required int, string, string*

I have tried putting the args within the event handler, however, it just creates a larger error.

I am relatively new to java and would really appreciate the help

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? Which line above causes the compiler to complain? Or is in a line not shown? Please post the full compiler's error message as well.

Comment: How are you calling it? Show that code and we might be able to help.

Comment: BTW: `(int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)` can be done with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

Comment: This call isn't going to change `p1total` in the calling method, because Java variables are passed by value.  I would recommend changing the signature to `public int hitCardp(String p1sCard1, String p1sCard2)`, returning `p1HitCard` and updating the total variable in the calling method.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information about your handler and class.

Error comes because of missing args.
your method have to be run as:

```
Hitcardp1(p1total,p1scard1,p1scard2);
```

also, you have missed `"` in your code.

`P1Area.setText("Card: " +p1scard1+ "\nCard: " +p1scard2+ "\nCard: "+p1hitcard);`

Comment: Thanks, I can edit in the rest of my program as well for context